# Google sheet api V4 Java: multiline cell value

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I'm using java Google sheet api v4 which works pretty well.
On thing I cannot figure out is the separator character for multiline cell value

Let say I have A2 cell in "mySheet" sheet which contains a multline value such as:
Value1
Value2
Value3

```
    String range = "mySheet!A2";
    ValueRange valueRange = sheetService.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetId(), range).execute();
    List<List<Object>> rowsValues = valueRange.getValues();
    for (List<Object> rowValues : rowsValues) {
        String rowValue = (String) rowValues.get(0);
        List<String> splittedValue = Arrays.asList(objectType.split(?????));
    }
```

I hope my question is clear enough.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

All data within a cell is just text, so if something is on multiple lines then it's separated with a linebreak character: `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.
As Sam said, I had already tried to split with a linebreak character.
But I ended up with a special character "&#xD";

Solution is to user Scanner class

```
    String range = "mySheet!A2";
    ValueRange valueRange = sheetService.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetId(), range).execute();
    List<List<Object>> rowsValues = valueRange.getValues();
    for (List<Object> rowValues : rowsValues) {
        String rowValue = (String) rowValues.get(0);
        List<String> splittedValue = new ArraysList<String>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(objectType);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            splittedValue .add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
```

Finally the list is clean and doesn't contain special charater.

Thanks for your help Sam